# Backup recommendation for Partitioned 64bit Domino (8.5) on Windows (2003 or 2008)

Tags: backup, 64-bit, ibm-domino

Does anyone have a recommendation for backup software that is compatible with partitioned, 64bit Domino software on Windows 2003 or 2008 server? Our current  solution handles neither, though they may do 64bit in the future.

I'm not worried about windows or other file backups - our Domino backups are already large enough to require their own environment (tape library etc.)

Update: Backup should be done through the Notes API - not through an open file agent. This is required for transaction log support (not in my original post).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [software compatibility list](ftp://exftpp.symantec.com/pub/support/products/Backup_Exec_for_WindowsNT/307063.pdf) on their site, Symantec's Backup Exec 12.5 supports what I need:

- 64bit Domino on 64bit OS
- 32bit Domino on 32bit OS
- Partitioned Servers
- Transaction log backups

Answer (score 0):

I have used eVault with excellent success and reliability on Domino. I used 32-bit, but according to their site it should also support 64-bit. It's a disk-to-disk solution and it supports open file backups. Their site is www.i365.com

Jes

Comment: Perfectly valid answer, but I didn't ask the right question the first time.